# How can I made edit to JavaScript file locally in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

How can I made edit to JavaScript file locally in Chrome?

I following this article:
https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

But in step 2, I can't edit the Javascript file. For some reason the file is ready only in the 'Sources' Panel.

How can I edit the javascript file locally?

Thank you.

Comment: seems to work fine for me. Keep in mind, your edits won't actually change the real files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just FYI: The article you linked to is from 2013. Chrome dev tools changes almost weekly.

Sometimes just doing hard refresh on the page will allow you to edit the .js file from the Sources panel. It should be as simple as right clicking and choosing `Save As...`.

If that doesn't work perhaps you could provide a url?